# In react native ,when recording audio,the output format is always mp4

Tags: react-native

In react native ,when recording audio, the output format is always mp4.Even when I change extension to .mp3  or .opus.  I am using react-native-audio package . I want the format to be ogg or opus

I try react-native-audio-record-player but same problem .

Comment: Why don't you use an API to send audio and get converted to ogg or opus format?

Comment: Also https://github.com/hyochan/react-native-audio-recorder-player/blob/main/index.ts supports opus encoding, see line#63

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ffmpeg-kit-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-kit-react-native?activeTab=readme) to convert your audio file extension.